# "undefined refrence to" when using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am implementing a simple project using opencv . but i am getting error undefined refrence while compiling it. this is world.cpp:(just the part the error occures)

```
#include "world.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define SSTR( x ) static_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
    ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()

World::World()
{
map = new Map;
agent = new Agent(map->GetTheState(0));
ExploringRate = 10000;
}

 void World::Monitor()
{
 Mat myMat(500,500,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0));
 for(int i = 0;i<100;i++)
 {
     string s = SSTR(map->GetTheState(i)->GetValue());
     int k = i/10;
     int j = i%10;
     if(map->GetTheState(i)->GetValue()>0)
         rectangle(myMat,Point(j*50,k*50),Point((j+1)*50,(k+1)*50),Scalar(0,255*map->GetTheState(i)->GetValue(),0),-1,CV_AA);
     else
         rectangle(myMat,Point(j*50,k*50),Point((j+1)*50,(k+1)*50),Scalar(-255*0.5,0,0),-1,CV_AA);
     putText(myMat,s,Point(j*50 +10,k*50 + 25),0,0.40,Scalar(255,255,255),1,0,false);
 }
 int k = agent->GetCurrentStateNumber()/10 , j = agent->GetCurrentStateNumber()%10;
 circle(myMat,Point(j*50 + 20,k*50 + 20),5,Scalar(0,0,255),+20,0);
 imshow("mymat",myMat);
 cvWaitKey(1);
}
```

and this is my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

OPENCV = `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs `
LIBS = $(OPENCV)
BOOST= -I./ -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -pthread
BOOSTFLAG= -lrt


all: main.o state.o agent.o map.o world.o
    $(CC) main.o state.o agent.o map.o world.o -o world

main.o: main.cpp world.h
    $(CC) -c main.cpp $(BOOST) $(LIBS) $(BOOSTFLAG)

state.o: state.cpp state.h 
    $(CC) -c state.cpp $(BOOST) $(LIBS) $(BOOSTFLAG)


agent.o: agent.cpp agent.h
    $(CC) -c agent.cpp $(BOOST) $(LIBS) $(BOOSTFLAG)

map.o: map.cpp map.h state.h
    $(CC) -c map.cpp $(BOOST) $(LIBS) $(BOOSTFLAG)

world.o: world.cpp world.h
    $(CC) -c world.cpp $(BOOST) $(LIBS) $(BOOSTFLAG)
```

when i want to make it , i get this error:

```
g++ main.o state.o agent.o map.o world.o -o world
world.o: In function `World::Monitor()':
world.cpp:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to `cv::rectangle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
world.cpp:(.text+0x3fd): undefined reference to `cv::rectangle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
world.cpp:(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::String const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
world.cpp:(.text+0x654): undefined reference to `cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
world.cpp:(.text+0x6ad): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
world.cpp:(.text+0x6d5): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
world.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x4d): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
world.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
world.o: In function `cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatC2EiiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE[_ZN2cv3MatC5EiiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE]+0xdb): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
world.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
world.o: In function `cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii[_ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii]+0x9d): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
world.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x4b): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
world.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
world.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN2cv6StringC5ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x69): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I have installed opencv from source file and have already tried

```
sudo ldconfig
```

i really need help

Comment: I believe the `pkg-config` stanza might need to include `--libs opencv`, not just `--libs`.

Comment: Thanks but I still have the error

Comment: Your "all" target (the one that does the linking) doesn't link against any libs.

Comment: I think @Miles is correct. Also, if interested, all C recipes should include `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) ...`; and all C++ recipes should include `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) ...`. Also see GNU make's [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) and [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html). Don't be turned off by the GNU. Most of the world follows most of it. The projects that seem to have chronic problems, like OpenSSL, don't follow the general ideas or basic rules.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked . I still have error but that problem was solved . Thank you so much